# Вернуть geometry при помощи binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Подскажите как действовать в такой ситуации... Есть Пользовательский контрол, внутри него лежит `rectangle`, БЕЗ `name`. Так вот как мне получить `Geometry Rectangle`'а без названия например из главной формы программы? Раньше я справлялся с помощью :

Код в пользовательском контроле :

```
public Geometry retgeometry()
{
    return (myfavouriterectangle.RenderedGeometry); // myfavouriterectangle - это название того самого rectangle'а из которого мы должны получить Geometry
}
```

Код в самой программе :

```
var controlgeometry = uiusercontrol.retgeometry();
```

А сейчас нужно избавится от `Name` и вот вспомнил про хорошую вещь как `Binding`.

**UPD** :
@VladD вот для чего ...

```
                var g = tb.retgeometry();
                g.Transform = (Transform)tb.TransformToAncestor(canvas);
                var m = (myui as uiusercontrol).retgeometry();
                m.Transform = (Transform)(myui as uiusercontrol).TransformToAncestor(canvas);
                IntersectionDetail khg = m.FillContainsWithDetail(g);
```

Comment: Окей, давайте поднимемся от деталей реализации к смыслу. Какую задачу вы решаете? В чём смысл этой геометрии для окружающего кода?

Comment: @VladD тему обновил

Comment: Всё равно не понятно. Вы с ней делаете какие-то вычисления — это я понял. А для чего, какой смысл за этим стоит?

Comment: @VladD Ну мне нужно просто проверить накладываются ли 2 пользовательских контрола, а retgeometry я делаю чтобы получить geometry их фонов rectangle. Можно конечно сделать всё проще, но у меня работает только так.

Comment: Окей, а почему тогда бы в usercontrol'е не не выставить `Geometry` как `DependencyProperty`? К нему можно будет привязываться снаружи. Но его нужно будет поддерживать в правильном и актуальном состоянии, разумеется.

Comment: @VladD а что значит "Но его нужно будет поддерживать в правильном и актуальном состоянии"?

Comment: Ну, если вы поменяли геометрию у прямоугольника, то и свойство нужно тут же обновить.

Comment: Не @VladD  , геометрия у меня не будет изменятся.

Comment: А, ну тогда можно просто обыкновенное свойство использовать.

Comment: @VladD осталось только разобраться со свойствами )

Comment: Ну, а что с ними разбираться? `public Geometry Geometry { get; }` + присваиваете значение в конструкторе.

Comment: @VladD это где, в программе или внутри контрола?

Comment: В code-behind контрола, конечно.

Comment: @VladD ну с этим всё понятно, так имя всё таки нужно будет в вашем случае "Geometry"?

Comment: Имя какое угодно. Я бы назвал `Geometry`, но может быть вам придёт в голову имя получше.